# How to use sqlSession on thread (daemon)

Tags: spring, daemon, mybatis

I'm using Spring framework, and making one daemon with `Thread :: setDaemon(true)`. I want to use `sqlSession` on daemon above, but

```
@Auto-wired 
private SqlSession sqlSession
```

is `null` on daemon thread.

Why is `sqlSessoin` `null` on daemon?

Comment: Please post your code with your question.

Comment: Its `@Autowired`. How are you creating the daemon thread?